# Getting value from javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to verify an id using javascript ajax.

An onclick event triggers the ajax call from within a function:

```
verified = verify_id($('#set_ex_id').val());
alert('Verified: ' + verified);
```

The verify_id function, upon success has this:

```
result = data;
alert("RESULT 1: " + result);
return result;
```

The alert Result 1 is 1, but the alert Verified is undefined

Comment: You question indicates that you are making an AJAX call, but the code you posted doesn't make any such call. Did you forget to include that part of the code?

Comment: I only supplied the parts I thought may be in question. yes, it is using ajax, which is the second snippet and is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ajax call is made on the `verify_id` function, then the value won't by assigned to `verified` inmediately. Any code that needs the return value from `verify_id` to execute should be placed in the success function of the ajax call.

You may set the async propertie of the ajax call to false, this way the execution will stop until the value arrives from the server, and you'll get the value you need in the `alert('Verified: ' + verified);` call. But this will also block the page untill the server response is ready.

Comment: Thanks. What ended up doing is adding a section in the ajax success response to handle the response.